# Positioning the AC servo from 0 to 360 degrees to return to the shortest path

Tags: c, labview

I am doing absolute positioning using AC servo.I calculated how many steps of pulse are needed for a full rotation of the servo and converted it to degrees between 0-360.
For the current situation.
For example, if the motor is in the zero position, if I give a position in the CW direction. It goes to that degree in the CW direction. There is no problem here.
If the motor is in the 0 position, if I give a negative position, it moves in the CCW direction.
If the motor has moved in the CCW (negative position) direction, if I give a positive position, it will return to the position where it went in the negative direction and switch to the positive position.The method I want to create here is to go to the position given between 0 and 360 from the nearest path, regardless of the negative or positive direction of the motor.
It is completely similar to the logic of a compass, but it has to take the closest path to the given location.I'm trying a few ways, but I can't calculate the shortest path.
I tried to explain a little in the picture below.
[image]
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are you saying you want to figure out whether the shortest adjustment from position X to position Y is clockwise or counterclockwise and to figure out the amount of that change?

Comment: Yes. I want to find the position where the servo motor should be sent to go to the actual position.
  For example: When the motor is at 20 degrees according to the compass logic,
If I give a command to go to 350 degrees, -10 degrees should be sent to the motor. In this way, it actually goes to 350 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

If X and Y are numbers of degrees from 0 to 360 (measuring clockwise from an origin), then Y−X is the number of degrees to go clockwise from X to get to Y. That may be a positive number or a negative number (or zero), indicating clockwise or counterclockwise. If −180 ≤ Y−X ≤ +180, then it is making a turn of less than half a circle, so use it. Otherwise, if Y−X < −180, use Y−X+360, or, if +180 < Y−X, use Y−X−360.

Comment: Well, if the motor actually moves in the CCW direction and reaches -350 (10 degrees according to the compass logic), if I send the command to go to the actual 350 degrees again, the engine should send the -370 command, because it should proceed from the nearest path and not return. how should i do this.

Comment: If the motor has moved away from 0 in the CCW direction, if I send a positive position to the motor, the motor comes back from the position it went in the CCW direction and goes to the CW direction position.